# ObservableArray.length stays 0. Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

that drives me crazy... I have checked a LOT of posts here related to my question, but still can not fix my problem. 
In short: 
I use '$.Ajax.BeginForm' to update my model observableArray. The data is there, the table is updated, but, when I am checking the length of that array, it stays 0! What Am I missing in here?

here is data:

ViewModel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //VIEW MODEL DECLARATION:
        var ViewModel = {
            SubscriberEmail: ko.observable(""),
            SubscriberLists: ko.observableArray([]),
            UnsubscribeAll: ko.observable(false),
            UpdateSubscriberLists: function ()
            {
                $.ajax("/Home/UpdateSubscriptionInfo/", {
                    data: ko.toJSON({ lists: this.SubscriberLists }),
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', data);
                    }
                });
            },
            ProcessUnsubscribeAll: function() {
                if (this.UnsubscribeAll)
                {
                    alert('changing');
                    alert(ViewModel.SubscriberLists().length);
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(ViewModel.SubscriberLists(), function (item)
                    {
                        alert("changing OptIn");
                        //item.OptIn = false;
                    });
                };
            }
        };

        //UTILITY FUNCTIONS:
        function DisplayMessage(data)
        {
            $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', data);
        }
        function ProcessListsReceived(data)
        {
            ViewModel.SubscriberLists(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));
        }

        //ON DOCUMENT LOADED:
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
        });
    </script>
```

Part that calls for update:

```
<div class="navbar-right form-inline" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetSubscriptionInfo",
                                       new AjaxOptions
                                           {
                                               HttpMethod = "POST",
                                               OnSuccess = "ProcessListsReceived"
                                           }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">&nbsp;</span>
                        <label class="sr-only" for="inputemail">Email address</label>
                        <input data-bind="text:SubscriberEmail" type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputemail" name="inputemail" placeholder="Enter your email" style="width: 300px;">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default input-sm btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Get my subscriptions</button>
                }
            </div>
```

The function that updates the observable array declared above in Javascript section -

```
 function ProcessListsReceived(data)
            {
                ViewModel.SubscriberLists(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));
            }
```

I have a button bound to the length of the array.. it ALWAYS stays disabled:

```
<button data-bind="click: UpdateSubscriberLists, enable: SubscriberLists().length > 0" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Update subscription</button>
```

SO.... why after the update the array length is 0?  Thanks for any tips!!

AL

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that 'ko.mapping.fromJSON' does not updates the length of my array in my case...
Rewriting teh code to do actual push did the trick and my array reflects correctly number of the elements.

So instead of :

```
 function ProcessListsReceived(data)
            {
                ViewModel.SubscriberLists(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));
            }
```

I have declared:

```
 var SubscriberList = function (id,name,desc,optin) {
            this.ListID = ko.observable(id);
            this.ListName = ko.observable(name);
            this.ListDescription = ko.observable(desc);
            this.OptIn = ko.observable(optin);
        };
```

and rewrote the function as:

```
function ProcessListsReceived(data) {
            $(jQuery.parseJSON(data)).each(function ()
            {
                ViewModel.SubscriberLists.push(new SubscriberList(this.ListID, this.ListName, this.ListDescription, this.OptIn));
            });
        }
```

now it works.  thanks,
Al